# Boost Spirit Qi Re-Establish Skipping with custom skip grammar

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a grammar that has, up until now, been using the standard `boost::spirit::ascii::space`/`boost::spirit::ascii::space_type` skipper.

I have some rules that use the skipper and some that don't, like

```
qi::rule<Iterator, PTR<Expression>(), ascii::space_type> expression;
qi::rule<Iterator, PTR<Term>()> term;
```

When I use a non-skipping nonterminal (like `term`) inside of a skipping nonterminal (like `expression`), everything works like I would expect - whitespace only matters inside the `term` nonterminal.

Further, up until now, I have been fine including nonterminals that use the skipper inside of nonterminals that don't using `qi::skip` to restablish skipping, such as

```
index = (qi::lit('[') >> qi::skip(ascii::space)[explist >> qi::lit(']')]);
```

This way, whitespace is not significant inside of the `[]` braces, but is outside.

However, now I want to add my own custom skipper (I want to make newlines significant and later add comment-skipping). My skipper grammar looks like:

```
struct skip_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
  qi::rule<Iterator> start;
  skip_grammar() : skip_grammar::base_type(start) {
    start = qi::char_("\t\r ");
  }
};
```

I have been able to add it into my rule definitions just fine like

```
qi::rule<Iterator, PTR<Expression>(), skip_grammar> expression;
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to use my skip grammar as an argument to `qi::skip` (and replace `ascii::space`). I've tried using the type, a local instance variable, and a global instance variable. The farthest I've gotten is to get clang to complain that my skip_grammar needs a copy constructor. So I tried adding a copy constructor to my skip grammar, but apparently the `boost::noncopyable` base class is there for a reason, because my binary segfaulted almost immediately.

How should I be using this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `qi::grammar` is just a container for `qi::rules`. It does not have a copy constructor because this could inadvertently create dangling references in the parser expressions on the right hand side of those rules.

Using a grammar as a skipper as you want to do it is a bit tricky and amounts to passing the start rule of the grammar to the skip parser. It might be easier to just create a rule instance for that (especially if you have a single rule skipper).

In any case, the rule needs to be passed to the skipper as a reference (by calling the rule's member function `alias()`):

```
skip_grammar skippper;
index = '[' >> qi::skip(skipper.start.alias())[explist >> ']'];
```

or simply:

```
rule<iterator> skipper = qi::char_("\t\r ");
index = '[' >> qi::skip(skipper.alias())[explist >> ']'];
```

The aliasing is necessary because of the specifics of what it means to copy a rule. It is described in more detail in Spirit's FAQ [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/faq/#aliases).

Comment: Okay fantastic. Thanks again for all your awesome help. As an aside, should I be using rules instead of grammars for skipping? I didn't think phrase_parse took the rule type for the skipper.

Comment: Any parser component can be utilized as a skipper for phrase_parse - no limitations there.

Comment: +1, the alias() was what I was looking for, I wasn't sure how to use it for a grammar, but applying it to the start rule in skip() makes sense! The MSVC diagnostic is useless here; only referring to C2248 without source trace.